# How do you format numbers in Excel for Indian Currency (Rupees)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, formatting

Currently the Excel default formatting is:

```
1,000,000
500,000
```

How do you format the number to use the comma separator (,) like this

```
10,00,00,000
50,00,000
```

This is is how Indian Currency (Rupees, INR, ₹) is normally represented.

Comment: What? You want it to have commas at position 3 and 5? 6? Between 0s? Is this for a currency? Your question is *very unclear*

Comment: Yes i want to put comma in 3 then 5 then 7 then 9 and so on position. This is because of my currency which is rupees. Kindly give me some solution for that..

Comment: http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/07/26/indian-currency-format-excel/

Answer (score 16):

Some currency systems require a slightly different comma schema.  With data like:

[image]

applying this *Custom Number Format* with decimal points:

```
[>=10000000]##\,##\,##\,##0;[>=100000] ##\,##\,##0;##,##0.00
```

will produce:

[image]

Comment: "Note that the original question is written wrong for India. In India the lowest-value 3 places are grouped together, then pairs of digits in higher places separated by commas. 100 1,000 10,000 1,00,000 10,00,000 1,00,00,000 and so on. So the results displayed in the answer above are actually correct for India." - Phil Davis

Comment: Can you convert this exact notation for US style three digit comma separation? I tried this but excel doesn't allow it: `[>=1000000000]##\,###\,###\,##0;;[>=1000000]##\,###\,##0;[>=1000] ##\,##0;##,##0`

Answer (score 3):

There is a better and permanent solution (for Indian users):

Add `Region` as `India` and language as `English(India)`. Then you can see the Indian comma format and Indian currency symbol inplace of dollar symbol. Default setting in `US` and `English(US)`.

Go to **Control panel > Region** (search)

(tab) **Format** : Select `English(India)`

Click `Laguage Preferences` and add `English(India)` and `move up` to top.

Press `OK`

Comment: The question clearly states that the user wants to format in Excel not system wide